# Kubernetes Podspec to download only container image but it should not install

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, podspec

I want to download the container image, but dont want to deploy/install the image.
How can i deploy podspec to download only images but it should not create container.
Any podspec snapshot for this?

Comment: Could you please tell the use case behind this question? Focusing specifically on image pull, I'd reckon there could be some ways (workarounds) like a `Daemonset` with overridden command and with `initContainters`, ansible module to connect to Nodes and pull the images, a `Job` with overridden command, etc.

Comment: We usually delete the pod and then create new pod with new image, Some times due to network connectivity, we get IMagepullerror, another use case is Downtime, if we pull image earlier then delete pod and create, it will save downtime bcz image pull will take time. 

So how can we have podspec to download only image. 

Any workaround for this, you mentioned daemon set and Init container. It would be helpful if you can provide more details and podspec or Init Containers content

Comment: Sure, give me some time and I will write my thoughts and potential solutions on that matter. In the meantime I'd recommend you checking following docs: [initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/), [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no direct Kubernetes resources to **only** download an image of your choosing. To have the images of your applications on your `Nodes` you can consider using following solutions/workarounds:

- Use a `Daemonset` with an `initContainer`('s)
- Use tools like Ansible to pull the images with a playbook

---

#### Use a `Daemonset` with `InitContainers`

Assuming the following situation:

You've created 2 images that you want to have on all of the `Nodes`.

You can use a `Daemonset` (spawn a `Pod` on each `Node`) with `initContainers` (with images as source) that will run on all Nodes and ensure that the images will be present on the machine.

An example of such setup could be following:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: pull-images
  labels:
    k8s-app: pull-images
spec:
  # AS THIS DAEMONSET IS NOT SUPPOSED TO SERVE TRAFFIC I WOULD CONSIDER USING THIS UPDATE STRATEGY FOR SPEEDING UP THE DOWNLOAD PROCESS
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 100
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: pull-images
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: pull-images
    spec:
      initContainers:
      # PUT HERE IMAGES THAT YOU WANT TO PULL AND OVERRIDE THEIR ENTRYPOINT
      -  name: ubuntu
         image: ubuntu:20.04 # <-- IMAGE #1
         imagePullPolicy: Always # SPECIFY THE POLICY FOR SPECIFIC IMAGE
         command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exit 0"]
      -  name: nginx
         image: nginx:1.19.10 # <-- IMAGE #2 
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent # SPECIFY THE POLICY FOR SPECIFIC IMAGE
         command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exit 0"]
      containers:
      # MAIN CONTAINER WITH AS SMALL AS POSSIBLE IMAGE SLEEPING
      - name: alpine
        image: alpine 
        command: [sleep] 
        args: 
        - "infinity"
```

Kubernetes `Daemonset` controller will ensure that the `Pod` will run on each `Node`. Before the image is run, the `initContainers` will act as a placeholders for the images. The images that you want to have on the `Nodes` will be pulled. The `ENTRYPOINT` will be overridden to not run the image continuously. After that the main container (`alpine`) will be run with a `sleep infinity` command.

This setup will also work when the new `Nodes` are added.

Following on that topic I would also consider checking following documentation on `imagePullPolicy`:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Containers: Images: Updating images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images)*

> A side note!
>
> I've set the `imagePullPolicy` for the images in `initContainers` differently to show you that you can specify the `imagePullPolicy` independently for each container. Please use the policy that suits your use case the most.

---

#### Use tools like Ansible to pull the images with a playbook

Assuming that you have `SSH` access to the `Nodes` you can consider using Ansible with it's community module (assuming that you are using `Docker`):

- `community.docker.docker_image`

Citing the documentation for this module:

> This plugin is part of the [community.docker collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/docker) (version 1.3.0).
>
> To install it use: `ansible-galaxy collection install community.docker`.
>
> #### Synopsis
>
> Build, load or pull an image, making the image available for creating containers. Also supports tagging an image into a repository and archiving an image to a `.tar` file.
>
> -- *[Docs.ansible.com: Ansible: Collections: Community: Docker: Docker image module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html)*

You can use it with a following example:

- `hosts.yaml`

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    node-1:
      ansible_port: 22
      ansible_host: X.Y.Z.Q
    node-2: 
      ansible_port: 22
      ansible_host: A.B.C.D
```

- `playbook.yaml`

```yaml
- name: Playbook to download images
  hosts: all
  user: ENTER_USER

  tasks:
  - name: Pull an image
    community.docker.docker_image:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      source: pull
    with_items:
    - "nginx"
    - "ubuntu"
```

> A side note!
>
> In the ansible way, I needed to install docker python package:
>
> `$ pip3 install docker`

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Controllers: Daemonset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Pods: initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)*